# How to solve the problem of using SimpleWebRTC live video?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, live

The servers are now assigned as follows:

1、 Simplewertc server:

open https://0.0.0.0 :8443/test/

Listening on 0.0.0.0:8443...

2、 Signal signaling server:

[ root@cxlp88888 signalmaster-master]# node server.js

&yet -- signal master is running at: http://8.210.218.124 :8888

3、 Coturn penetration server:

[ root@cxlp88888 bin]# turnserver -v -r 8.210.218.124:3478 -a -o

0: log file opened: /var/log/turn_ 17866_ 2020-10-24.log

0: Listener address to use: 172.18.172.239

However, we use the firebox browser to test the effect of the PC side web page video. The debug is as follows:

First, you will be prompted with a warning: in the face of potential security risks, click accept the risk and continue ~, and then the start chat interface will appear, as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIeHb.png)

Click, create it! And then there will be no solution to the cross source request! The screenshot of the problem is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cAw0.png)

Now there are the following questions:

Question Q1: is it possible to solve the cross source problem and make the video normal? If not, which link has not been done well?

Question Q2: if the cross source problem can be solved, how to handle it in which file?

Is there a god of live video development? Please help me. ~~~~~~~

Comment: Can you post the text of the error message from the browser console in english? It is hard to read, but I see something about CORS -- that may be a good hint of what the problem is.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "make the video normal"? If the video started streaming at all, that may be important information to help determine the source of the problem.